# Find all positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ are both primes and $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)=c^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ are both primes and
$$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)=c^2+1$$

What I have done:

It is obvious that $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ cannot be both 2, so assume, WLOG, that $a^2+1=2$. Then, $a=1$
$$2(b^2+1)=c^2+1 \Rightarrow 2b^2+1=c^2 \Rightarrow b=2, c=3$$
Hence, we have 2 sets of solutions $(a, b, c)=(2, 1, 3); (1, 2, 3)$
If both $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ are odd primes, then $a, b, c$ are all even numbers.

I tried using Fermat's Infinite Descent by letting $a=2a_1, b=2b_1, c=2c_1$ but I seem to reach a dead end. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show how the General formula allows us to solve this equation.

$$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)=c^2+1$$

We write this equation differently.

$$c^2-(a^2+1)b^2=a^2$$

Will do the replacement.  $c=q+(k-1)b$

Then the equation takes the form.

$$q^2+2(k-1)qb+(k^2-2k-a^2)b^2=a^2$$

Now you can use the General formula.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Let the root equal to 1.  This means that using the solutions of the equation Pell.

$$k^2-2a^2=1$$
Knowing the first solution.
$$(k_0 ; a_0) - (3 ; 2)$$
You can find the following solution to the formula.
$$k=3k_0+4a_0$$

$$a=2k_0+3a_0$$

Using the General formula and the solution of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-(a^2+1)s^2=\pm1$$

You can write the solution of the equation in this form.

$$c=kp^2\pm2(a^2+1)ps+k(a^2+1)s^2$$

$$b=p^2\pm2kps+(a^2+1)s^2$$