# Finding all integral solutions to a particular problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Im working on some problems in Arthur Engel's problem solving strategies book and one of the problems is:

On page 132: the question is:

[image]

Now here is what the back of the book says:

[image]

So I am trying to find the other solution based on the last sentence. My guess is it would involve modular arithmetic as well.

I started of with $\mod 8$ but then I realize that wouldnt help me. I tried expanding back to the original problem that didnt help me either. I believe Engel left the end that way for a reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525416/find-all-positive-integers-a-b-c-such-that-a21-and-b21-are-both-prim/1525578#1525578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the author had in mind. But here is something that does use the suggested $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=z^2+1$.

Imagine that we know, as in the post, that $x$ and $y$ must be even. Suppose one of them, say $x$, is non-zero. Then $x^2-1$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, and is $\ne -1$, so it is divisible by a prime $p$ of the shape $4k+3$.

Then $p$ divides $z^2+1$, that is, $z^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. But it is a standard result of elementary number theory that the congruence $t^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: Are you saying that $x^2-1$ is not congruent to -1 modulo 4? Also where did you get x^2-1 is divisible by a prime p because in 4k+3 if k=3 we get 15 which is not prime. I am guessing there is a reason behind the fact that you are choosing prime numbers but i dont see it.

Comment: And if both are odd, $z^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}.$

Comment: @kero Write a prime factorization of $x^2-1$. They all have to be odd. $x^2-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Can all the prime factors be $\equiv 1\pmod 4$?

Comment: When I say that $x^2-1\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, I am saying exactly the same thing as $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @thomas did you mean prime not odd? because if x=3 then i have 9-1=8 and the prime factorization is $2^3$ but 2 is not odd.

Comment: I am assuming that we have done the congruential work that shows $x$ and $y$ are both even.

Comment: @kero We were assuming $x$ is even.

Comment: But your argument works if either $x,y$ even. My comment above handles the case when both odd. @AndréNicolas

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my mistake. you are right. Also if either x or y is odd and the other even then $z^2$ would also be 3 mod 4?